# How to print a formatted string with a space before positive numbers and +

Tags: java

I can do this:

```
public class first{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String message = String.format("%s, next year you'll be % +d", "Michael", 37);
        System.out.printf(message);
    }
}
```

Not working: I get a runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = '+ '
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkNumeric(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
        at first.main(first.java:3)
```

Well, I can use only space symbol or +. Then it is working. But how can I combine the two?

Comment: String.format("%s, next year you'll be +%d", "Michael", 37);

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: Please use escape for %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.format("%s, next year you'll be +%d", "Michael", 37);`

This will print, `Michael, next year you'll be +37`

Just a tip, most people tend to capitalize their class files, ie, `First` instead of your name, `first`. Of course if you are working alone you can name anything anyway you want and whatever you want to call it. But, if you start working with teams then you should try and work on your format.

**Edit**: Someone commented that you want a space so just throw in a space like this, `+ %d`

Comment: I think the OP wants a space after the `+`, but I think he gets the idea.

Comment: @Algorithmist OP == "Original Poster"

Answer (score 1):

Try this, added escape for %

```
String message = String.format("%%s, next year you'll be %% +d", "Michael", 37);
```

This will solve error, but to resolve formatting try:

```
String message = String.format("%s, next year you'll be +%d", "Michael", 37);
```

Cheers !!

Comment: @DummyCode: of course it will compile. It will just give wrong output :P

Comment: @anubhava Nope, try and run it.

Comment: @DummyCode: I wouldn't have commented had I not run it in the code. Please enlighten why first line won't compile?

Comment: @SachinThapa: Even after edit your output will be: `%s, next year you'll be +37`

Comment: @DummyCode: See demo: http://ideone.com/TbRueF (as I said it compiles but gives wrong output).

Comment: @anubhava It compiles but it does not run.

Comment: @DummyCode: That is what I have been saying that **it will compile**. However it will also run as you can see from the linked demo.

Comment: Edit !! Both compiles, first has wrong output, second one has correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `"%s, ... + %d", "str", 37`